# How to Get List Of Countries in Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, picklist, country-and-state

I'm aware that Salesforce provides a native way to use country and state values in Account and Contact address fields. But what if I want to use apex to get those list of countries so that I can use them in a custom LWC? Is there a way?

(I tried [this](https://skaruz.com/salesforce-how-to-access-state-and-country-picklists-values-in-apex/), but I'm not sure the data structure matches my environment, as it's looking for a "MailingCountry" field in the Contact object, but that doesn't exist).

Answer (score 2):

The `MailingAddress` and `ShippingAddress` fields are special *[compound fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields.htm)*. They're read-only, and hide the fact that there are indeed separate fields backing them.

So while you won't find `MailingCountry` explicitly listed as a field on the `Account` or `Contact` object, the field does in fact exist.

This information is also corroborated by the [SOAP API documentation for Contact](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) (you'll find `MailingAddress`, followed by `MailingCity`, `MailingState`, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

As Derek mentioned, `MailingCountry` is part of the `MailingAddress` [compound field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_address.htm) on the `Contact` object. So it should exist.

Another possible explanation for your issue is that you don't have State and Country/Territory Picklists [enabled in your org](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_state_country_picklist_enable.htm&type=5).

Once you have that enabled, the first block of code in the blog entry you linked should work, although it's more verbose than it needs to be.  The 2nd block of code is incorrect (You can't just instantiate a `List` in Apex, it has to be a list of something specific. Also, you do need to use `MailingCountryCode` instead of `MailingCountry` in this case.)

I enabled State and Country/Territory Picklists in my dev org.  After that, the following code worked for me in Execute Anonymous:

```java
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> values = Contact.MailingCountryCode
  .getDescribe()
  .getPickListValues();
List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
for (Schema.PicklistEntry v : values) {
    options.add(new SelectOption(v.getLabel(), v.getLabel()));
}
System.debug(options);
```